# Hyphenation on next-to-last line

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

On the next-to-last line of a paragraph, I have some hyphenation and on the last line, I only have the end of the word.

```
blablabla cou-
cou.
New paragraph
```

I thought the command `\finalhyphendemerits` could resolve this problem, but it doesn't seems to…

Any idea ?
I’m using `memoir` class and XeLaTeX

Comment: What value are you setting `\finalhyphendemerits` to?

Comment: \finalhyphendemerits=10000

Comment: That's comparable to `\penalty 100` when talking of line or page breaks, so it's not high enough; try 50000000.

Answer (score 7):

The value of `\finalhyphendemerits` should by much higher. Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\textwidth=18pc
\begin{document}
\hyphenpenalty=-5000
\finalhyphendemerits=50000000

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

The setting of `\hyphenpenalty` is just to invite TeX to hyphenate more frequently. Notice that the last line doesn't have a hyphen.

[image]