# How do I encourage hyphenation at the end of the next-to-last line of a paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs, hyphenation

My question is similar to an inverse of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62359/hyphenation-on-next-to-last-line) question.  In my document, which is large, there are numerous instances where a long word at the end of the next-to-last line is pushed to the last line, creating an overly sparse next-to-last line.  In many of these cases, I have tried inserting `\-` into the long word, but this does not induce hyphenation.  Reducing `\finalhyphendemerits` to 100 or even to 1 also fails to fix the problem.  Is there anything I can do, short of explicitly breaking these long words with a `\linebreak`?

---

My related settings are

```
\pretolerance=500
\tolerance=1000
\hyphenpenalty=5000
\finalhyphendemerits=100
```

Comment: If you can show an example document people can probably help you. That is, make a complete document with just one paragraph that shows the unwanted behaviour.

Comment: You might set `\finalhyphendemerits` to a large *negative* value, but you should definitely reduce `\hyphenpenalty`: with so high `\tolerance=1000` it is rather unlikely that paragraphs can be set without hyphenation.

Answer (score 2):

You have `\hyphenpenalty` set *very* large. The default is 50. 5,000 is halfway to TeX's concept of infinity.